# Drag-and-drop on a web part not working

Tags: web-part, document-library, office-365, drag-and-drop

I've just encountered a funny glitch in O365 in which I can't drag-and-drop files into a document library through its web part displayed on a web part page. Drag-and-drop works fine on the library itself, it only fails on the web part, and it's consistent across browsers and different versions of Windows/Office. I can't find any TechNet articles or questions about this situation occurring for O365, only for SP2013, and the solution doesn't help me in this case.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: Works fine for me. I tested on a SharePoint online site on blank web part page. Do you see any javascript errors? Try on a completely blank web part page without any other web parts.

Comment: There's a `SyntaxError` on page load in `platform_embed.js`, and nothing appears to be amiss when I actually try the drag-and-drop.

Comment: I did just realize the library in question is actually on a sub-site. I haven't yet exported and added it to its own page on the parent site, but I did create that page and add the local "Documents" library to it and the drag-and-drop works fine, so perhaps it's got something to do with the fact its in a sub-site?

Comment: I'm curious... how did you add a library web part from subsite to a page on parent site?

Comment: It wasn't actually done by me so I can only guess, but I think the person exported the web part from the other site and manually added it to this one.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue. This appears to be a limitation whereby SP.Utilities.CommandBlock does not get loaded to a published page in view mode. It will work for site collection admins, but not for owners/members/visitors. For non-site coll admins, the workaround is to check out the page, and then perform the drag-and-drop upload.